The problem in the derivation of displacement current in Maxwell's equations

I think there’s an issue with this process: does a real current always exist where there is displacement current?
Despite that, how can I better derive the displacement current?
By the way, if there is no current generated by the movement of charges exist at the location where there is displacement current, then there is no actual charges at that location, how can I use the first Maxwell's equation to derive the relation between the displacement current and the time-varying electrical field?

The derivation does not define $j_0$ so it looks like nonsense to me. Gauss' law is defined using total charge, you can work backwards from that maybe, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Equivalence_of_total_and_free_charge_statements

Ah, maybe $j_0$ is a typo for $j_D$ and maybe $j_d$ is a typo for $j_D$. A bit sloppy.

I don't think "real current" is correct terminology, you perhaps mean "total charge current". Not sure about your claim, why can the mix of positive and negative charges not move in a way so their net movement makes the total charge current zero? If all charges in a crystal wiggle like a static grid or something similar to that...

sorry for type mistake, I have modified the text

I don't think there is a problem with this approach, other than to call it a "derivation".
What it does is indicate that in a situation where you have a changing charge density, that you must introduce a displacement current density of the form $\epsilon_0 \partial \vec{E}/\partial t$ to maintain agreement between Ampere's law and the equation of charge continuity.
Once you have introduced that extra term you can hypothesise that such an Ampere's law holds in all circumstances (in fact, the displacement current density term has to be modified to $\partial \vec{D}/\partial t$ to deal with a changing polarisation in media).
Displacement current can of course exist in regions with no charge at all - between the plates of a charging capacitor is the usual example - and you can demonstrate the need for a displacement current density term in Ampere's law with that specific example too.
This also is not a "derivation".
